# How to make colspan auto when td is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to make colspan auto. Actually, I have created a dynamic table but sometimes td goes to empty so that time I want to expand my column width but I don't have an idea about this. Is it possible to auto colspan or any other method to do this?

You can see my table below:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td>General or OBC</td>
        <td>125</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>SC or ST</td>
       <td>65</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PH Candidates</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pay the Exam Fee Through SBI Mops Debit Card, Credit Card, Net Banking or SBI E Challan Mode Only</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

here is my PHP code also,

```
<table class="feedetails" id="feedetails">
              <tr class="tblhead">
                 <th class="inricon" colspan="2">APPLICATION FEE</th>
              </tr>
              <?php
                   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM appfee where joblink=? and status='y' order by id asc");
                   if ($stmt->execute(array($joblink))) {
                      $rows = $stmt->rowCount();
                      if ($rows == "") {
                        echo '<style type="text/css">.feedetails{display: none;}</style>';
                      }else{
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  
                          echo'<tr>
                               <td>'.$row['category'].'</td>
                               <td>'.$row['fee'].'</td>
                            </tr>';
                        }
                      }
                   }
                ?>
          </table>
```

Comment: Well it looks like you will have to do that in PHP so show us the PHP code that created this HTML

Comment: ok, sir, I have added my PHP code now you can see in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `while` loop to this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if($row['fee']  !== '') { // if $row['fee'] is not empty then echo two TDs
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['category'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['fee'].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    else { // otherwise, echo one TD with colspan == 2
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">'.$row['category'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: That saved me the bother

Comment: Thanks, dear brother :)

Comment: it's so simple.